# UnhandledPromiseRejection when returning promise in async-await function

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I've already searched among a lot of questions asked by other users but I can't still figure out why my function doesn't work properly.
I wrote this code:

```
async function getFile(c, sourcePath, fileName, destPath) {
    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      c.cwd(sourcePath, function(err, currentDir) { // "c" is an instance of ftp module's class, "cwd" is one of its methods to change working directory
        err = new Error('trying to throw an error for testing the func');
        if (err) reject(err);
        c.get(fileName, function(err, stream) {
          if (err) reject(err);
          stream.once('close', function() { resolve(); });
          stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(destPath));
        });
      });
    }));
}

(async function() {
  try {
    await getFile(c, '/path/to', 'file.xls', 'file.xls');

  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
})();
```

Node returns an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`, and I don't understand why. I have returned a promise in the first function and then called that function in another one correctly structured with async-await syntax. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: What line is it complaining about?

Comment: @evolutionxbox it refers to the line where I created the new fake error to reject: `err = new Error('trying to throw an error for testing the func');`. Same happens if I directly write `reject(new Error('trying to throw an error for testing the func'))`

Comment: also please be aware that nesting `new Promise` inside an async function is unnecessary.

Comment: @evolutionxbox in this case, `async-await` is unnecessary.

Comment: What catches the exception thrown inside the `catch` block?

Comment: Well you are throwing again inside the last catch..

Comment: @Yousaf yup. Good clarification

Comment: @callback oh. My fault, beg your pardon :D

Comment: As said by @callback you're throwing the error in the last catch block. The original error is the one you wrote and it's coming from that line so node tells you that that is the error but of course you're not handling it since you're throwing it in the last catch. Also, `async` is unecessary because you're returning a new Promise and since `return await new Promise` is the only statement of your function you don't need to `await` it, just `return new Promise` will be enough

Comment: @Nick yes, thanks. It was the habit of using node frameworks with error propagation, I forgot that this was just a simple script. And thanks for the correction on the useless async function